# Unable to register extension org.sonar.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaSensor from plugin 'cobertura'

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Since I updated  my sonarqube server to 6.1 I'm getting this error in my gradle project.

I'm using sonar plugin latest version (2.2)

`classpath("org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.2")`

anyone knows how to solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this problem by delete the cobertura jar file in the plugins folder. It seems sonarqube 6.1 does not support cobertura any more. because after i delete the file i can't find cobertura in the sonar plugin management page.